# Print date time repeatedly after specific time period

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I want to print the code exactly after one min

```
import time
from datetime import datetime
while True:
    time.sleep(1)
    now = datetime.now()
    current_datetime = now.strftime("%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S")
    if current_datetime==today.strftime("%d-%m-%Y") + "09:15:00":
        sec = 60
        time.sleep(sec)
        print("time : ", current_datetime)
```

I am trying to achieve these steps.

1. Start running the code at or before 09 am.
2. check if exactly 09.15 am today
3. print the time
4. Run after exactly 1 min and print time.

Output :

```
'2021-06-14 09:15:00+05:30'
'2021-06-14 09:16:00+05:30'
'2021-06-14 09:17:00+05:30'
'2021-06-14 09:18:00+05:30'
'2021-06-14 09:19:00+05:30'
'2021-06-14 09:20:00+05:30'
```

and so on till '2021-06-14 14:30:00+05:30'

What is the best pythonic way to do this?

Comment: Do you mean you wish to print the time for every minute after 9:15  till 14:30?

Comment: yes wanted to do that.

Answer (score 1):

I probably would do it this way

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import time

# Prepare variables (optional)
format = '%Y%m%d'
s_offset = timedelta(hours=9, minutes=15)
e_offset = timedelta(hours=14, minutes=30)
today = datetime.strptime(datetime.strftime(datetime.now(), format), format)

# Sleep to 09:15
time.sleep((today + s_offset).timestamp() - datetime.now().timestamp())

while datetime.now() <= today + e_offset:
    print(datetime.strftime(datetime.now(), format + '%H:%M:%S'))
    next_minute = datetime.now() + timedelta(minutes=1)
    next_minute -= timedelta(microseconds=next_minute.microsecond)
    # There is still some minor precision error
    time.sleep(next_minute.timestamp() - datetime.now().timestamp())
```

If precision is not that important, you may just `time.sleep(60)` in the loop.

The error comes from the execution time, like `print()`. Because it takes a little time to print, `time.sleep(60)` would make your next loop later than more than 1 minute, and as the loop goes, the lag accumulates.

My approach here is neither perfect, but the error is not cumulative.

---

As an illustration

`time.sleep(1)`:

```
2021-06-14 00:17:32.000943
2021-06-14 00:17:33.002100
2021-06-14 00:17:34.002950
2021-06-14 00:17:35.003826
2021-06-14 00:17:36.004899
2021-06-14 00:17:37.005018
2021-06-14 00:17:38.005386
2021-06-14 00:17:39.005517
2021-06-14 00:17:40.005897
2021-06-14 00:17:41.006309
2021-06-14 00:17:42.006673
2021-06-14 00:17:43.007091
2021-06-14 00:17:44.007445
2021-06-14 00:17:45.007853
2021-06-14 00:17:46.008831
```

My approach:

```
2021-06-14 00:17:48.000917
2021-06-14 00:17:49.000290
2021-06-14 00:17:50.000906
2021-06-14 00:17:51.000326
2021-06-14 00:17:52.000929
2021-06-14 00:17:53.000265
2021-06-14 00:17:54.000915
2021-06-14 00:17:55.000483
2021-06-14 00:17:56.000719
2021-06-14 00:17:57.000841
2021-06-14 00:17:58.000428
2021-06-14 00:17:59.000890
2021-06-14 00:18:00.000909
2021-06-14 00:18:01.000943
2021-06-14 00:18:02.000704
```

Both loops start when microseconds=0.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind, You can just use python module called schedule (not pyschedule) - Python job scheduling for humans

`pip install schedule`

your need:

- start at 9:15
- print time (do the job) every 1 min
- until 16:30

`schedule` cannot set job start time AFAIK, but you can make a "do once job" to schedule another routing job:

```
import schedule
import time
from datetime import datetime

def start_once_job():
    #run routing job here if you want to do the job at 9:15:00
    job()
    # set new schedule to run every minute at the 00 second until 16:30
    # add 1 min if you want to do the job at 16:30:00
    #(because sleep(1) set to exactly 1 second to check, I think)
    schedule.every().minute.at(':00').until("2021-06-14 16:31").do(job)
    # cancel start_once_job
    return schedule.CancelJob

def job():
    # do w/e you want
    print(f'print time I want: {str(datetime.now())}')

schedule.clear() # clean all jobs for dev
schedule.every().day.at('09:15').do(start_once_job)

while True:
    schedule.run_pending()
    time.sleep(1)
```

my test screenshot:

[image]

note:

- It's a schedule, program will not stop (While True:), you can give some condition in While loop to break the loop.
- there's a little time shift depend on your `event loop` speed, e.g. `time.sleep(1)` should get a shift within 1s.

[image]

- with `time.sleep(0.1)`, function running time will become more important and let shift not within 0.1s

[image]

see https://schedule.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html for more examples.

Comment: in long run , the program running time will be not accurate?

since the first row is .116351
second is .183448

in long run the time will shift.

Comment: I have not tested, but I think a little shift is come from `time.sleep(1)` 'event loop' and some delay from run job after trigger. I'll test more period to check whether the error should be within 2 seconds IMO.